# objective-c static library intellij appcode

Tags: objective-c, static-libraries

New to objective-c.  Finally found a  [tutorial](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/04/04/using-open-source-static-libraries-in-xcode-4/) that describes how to create and use a static library in x-code.  I'm surprised that building and using libraries is such an arduous process.  Is there a more efficient way to create and use static libraries?

I installed JetBrain app-code.  But I can't follow the same steps since I can't figure out how to create a workspace in app-code.

Could someone please lists the steps for creating and using a static library in app-code?

Also, how can I change my build path in app-code?  I tried to change the path in project properties...there is a text-box but its value keeps reverting back to the default?

I think I'm missing something, because the jet-brain products I've worked with (resharper for C#, and intell-j for Java) are very high quality.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Is there a more efficient way to create and use static libraries?" - get rid of Xcode, use make & emacs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

at this moment, AppCode doesn't have full project configuration facilities: you cannot create targets in it. This functionality will be added in the [future versions](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-561).

Meanwhile, you can use Xcode to setup you project and then switch back to AppCode.

As for the build path reverting to the default, could you please file a bug report in the [tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/OC)?